# Error running '__rvm_make install'

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I'm new to programming trying to add Ruby 2.2 using RVM and receiving the below error.  I've run rvm get stable and tried reinstalling, but getting the same error.

```
$ rvm reinstall ruby-2.2.0
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.10/x86_64/ruby-2.2.0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system.....
Installing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config, libyaml, readline, libksba, openssl........
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' are already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.2.0 - #downloading ruby-2.2.0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12.6M  100 12.6M    0     0   892k      0  0:00:14  0:00:14 --:--:-- 1518k
ruby-2.2.0 - #extracting ruby-2.2.0 to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.2.0....
ruby-2.2.0 - #applying patch /usr/local/rvm/patches/ruby/2.2.0/fix_installing_bundled_gems.patch.
ruby-2.2.0 - #configuring..........................................................
ruby-2.2.0 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.2.0 - #compiling.............................................................
ruby-2.2.0 - #installing..........
Error running '__rvm_make install',
showing last 15 lines of /usr/local/rvm/log/1420687911_ruby-2.2.0/install.log
                              psych 2.0.8
                              rake 10.4.2
                              rdoc 4.2.0
installing bundle gems:       /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0 (build_info, cache, doc, extensions, gems, specifications)
                              minitest-5.4.3.gem
                              power_assert-0.2.2.gem
                              test-unit-3.0.8.gem
./tool/rbinstall.rb:723:in `chmod': Operation not permitted @ chmod_internal - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/ (Errno::EPERM)
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:723:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:749:in `call'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:749:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:746:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:746:in `<main>'
make: *** [do-install-nodoc] Error 1
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make install. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: I tried that as well and still same issue

Comment: why is there a ruby version in your gem folder?  delete this `/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/`

Comment: Thanks Anthony!  There were actually 4 ruby versions in the gems folder.  I removed all of them and the install completed.

Comment: I have same issue on ubuntu

Answer (score 52):

Try to update your rvm using command

```sh
rvm get head
```

Then try again. Hopefully it should work.

Comment: Worked! I guess any time you see an error while installing ruby with rvm, it's worth trying 'rvm get head'

Comment: After that command, I had to run `rvm reload` to get everything working.

Comment: when i used above command, it caused issue in existing ruby versions.

Answer (score 7):

This error got me scratching my head when installing ruby through **RVM** on an M1 Macbook:

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j10',
please read /Users/copmputer/.rvm/log/1640263012_ruby-2.4.0/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

First you need to inspect the file make.log and see what the underlying error is. In my case it was:

```
error: implicit declaration of function 'ffi_prep_closure' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

I found the complete solution to my problem on [this GitHub page](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/869). Here it is:

Step 1
Run in terminal: `brew info libffi` which will output the following:

```
For compilers to find libffi you may need to set:
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/include"

For pkg-config to find libffi you may need to set:
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Step 2
Run all 3 export commands in terminal to set the env variables.

Step 3
Finally, run the ruby installation command. In my case, it was:

```
rvm install ruby-2.4.0
```

That's it.

In case you're using rbenv there's another working solution in that GH thread.

Answer (score 7):

RubyGems is more secure now and you must have openssl installed for rvm to work. rvm doesn't come with the newest openssl libs out of the box, so for now you have to add its package, and also specify the path to your openssl configuration when installing a new ruby. The nature of the error doesn't really present itself, and it's a bit of a pain when installing new rubies, but maybe this will be changed in the future.

To verify if this is your situation, if you still have access to your log file, check it to see if it is failing on the openssl library. Alternatively, you can run `ruby -ropenssl -e "puts :OK"` to see if you get an error (this assumes you have a different ruby version installed you can use).

If either are true, then follow these two OS-agnostic steps:

```bash
rvm pkg install openssl
```

Then either

```bash
rvm install <ruby version here> --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

or

```bash
rvm reinstall <ruby version here> --force --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

...based on whether it was a new or pre-existing install of ruby.

Answer (score 4):

This [brilliant answer on github](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/5047#issuecomment-1597467044) has solved the problem for me. The solution is to simply use openssl while installing the version of ruby you wish to install. For example, to install ruby v2.7.8, run the command:

`rvm install ruby-2.7.8 --with-openssl-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1`

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue in October 2022, solved by refreshing the keys running

```
gpg2 --refresh-keys
```

Or you can try

```
gpg --refresh-keys
```

If you don't have gpg2 installed.

As RVM says [in their docs](https://rvm.io/rvm/security):

> It is a good practice to periodically refresh keys status to ensure
> none of them got revoked. You can also add it to cron.

Answer (score 1):

I also had to face the same problem while installation
**ruby's** in **ubutnu 22.04**
I resolved by these

rvm pkg install openssl
rvm install ruby-2.7.3 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr

Answer (score 0):

Following steps worked for me:

```
cd .rvm/src/ruby-x.x.x
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be with an outdated version of xcode. Try updating xcode from the app store. Then run `brew upgrade`. After that, you should be able to successfully install ruby with your rvm command.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I tried to install ruby-2.7.5. The following steps helped me install it without errors.

1. Update the RVM installer by running `rvm get head` from the terminal.

> If this step fails, you might want to update `curl` by running `brew install curl`

2. Now install openssl@1.1 as ruby-2.7.5 requires the same. You can do it by running `brew install opensssl@1.1`. Once done, update your `.zshrc` or `.zshenv` with the env variables suggested by the installation.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

3. Now install ruby-2.7.5 by running `rvm install 2.7.5`

**PS:** I also ran the following command after installing openssl@1.1 to fix the issues with the CA certs as suggested by the installation report. `/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin/c_rehash`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
arch -x86_64 rvm install 3.3.0 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1
```