# "error while running make install" when trying to install ruby via rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I'm using macOS and I'm trying to install ruby 2.4.1 via rvm. here is a log from my console

```
RETINA15M14:folder moi$ rvm install 2.4.1
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.12/x86_64/ruby-2.4.1.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/moi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.4.1 - #downloading ruby-2.4.1, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.4.1 - #extracting ruby-2.4.1 to /Users/moi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.4.1....
ruby-2.4.1 - #applying patch /Users/moi/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.4.1/random_c_using_NR_prefix.patch.
ruby-2.4.1 - #configuring..................................................................
ruby-2.4.1 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.4.1 - #compiling...............................................................
ruby-2.4.1 - #installing.....
Error running '__rvm_make install',
please read /Users/moi/.rvm/log/1506928428_ruby-2.4.1/install.log
There has been an error while running make install. Halting the installation.
```

and here is what in the log https://pastebin.com/Lh3V0s2P , I'm not sure what to do next I tried every option I found I could find and nothing helped. please tell me what whats wrong and how can it be solved.

Comment: Try  using `rvm install ruby-2.4.1` Also, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832732/error-running-rvm-make-install. Does this help?

Comment: @Aakanksha same error, https://pastebin.com/u5s7vUT2 `error while running make install`

Comment: @Aakanksha when im trying to do `rvm get head` i get this error https://pastebin.com/Cd7wJWv5 and reinstalling give the same error as above

Comment: Side note: Is there a good reason why you are installing `2.4.1`? You should always aim to use the latest patch release of the minor version - which, at present, is `2.4.2`.

Comment: hey @Tom, yes there is a reason for it. I'm working on a project that required to run on 2.4.1. does it has to do anything with the error ? I'll check anyway if installing 2.4.2 makes any errors

Comment: @TomLord even for 2.4.2 I get the same error for `Error running '__rvm_make install'`

Comment: No, @greW. Installing `2.4.1` for a project that requires `2.4.1` constitutes as a "good reason". (Although one should still aim to upgrade the project when possible.) I only mentioned this because it's very common for people to install old versions of ruby simply because they're copying commands from an out-of-date tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the following before installing ruby.

```
xcode-select --install
```

[Refer](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87097) here.