# Trying to install RVM and getting: Error running '__rvm_make -j2'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, macos-high-sierra

I was trying to install RVM with stable ruby on a mac and got a make error:

**abbreviated console output:**

```
   \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io
   ...
   ...
   ... 
   ruby-2.4.1 - #extracting ruby-2.4.1 to /Users/bbush/.rvm/src/ruby-2.4.1....
   ruby-2.4.1 - #applying patch /Users/bbush/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.4.1/random_c_using_NR_prefix.patch.
   ruby-2.4.1 - #configuring...................................................................
   ruby-2.4.1 - #post-configuration.
   ruby-2.4.1 - #compiling...........
   Error running '__rvm_make -j2',
```

**abbreviated make.log:**

```
............
compiling enc/us_ascii.c
compiling enc/unicode.c
compiling enc/utf_8.c
compiling enc/trans/newline.c
linking miniruby
generating encdb.h
make: ./miniruby: Permission denied
make: ./miniruby: Permission denied
make: *** [.rbconfig.time] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [encdb.h] Error 1
++ /scripts/functions/support : __rvm_make()  383 > return 2
```

**System**

- Mac OS X – High Sierra (10.13.4)
- Homebrew 1.6.9

I'm thinking that using sudo with the RVM install curl command is a bad idea but how do I get around this permissions issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried googling the error and trying the commands that come up? looks like it might be an openssl error

Comment: Have you made yourself a `root` user on your machine? Also, see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27832732/error-running-rvm-make-install

Answer (score 2):

I got this error in MacOS Catalina,

If you are installing ruby ​like this

```
rvm install 2.4 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`
```

**Try instead:**

```
rvm install 2.4 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl
```

The issue might be that you've got several Openssl versions installed

You can check it with,

```
ls -la /usr/local/opt/ | grep openssl
```

These steps worked for me:

```
$ gpg2 --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB

$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
$ brew install openssl
$ rvm install 2.4 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/openssl
```

Answer (score 1):

Double check that you have xcode installed and possibly gnupg.

```
brew install gnupg
```

Source:
http://usabilityetc.com/articles/ruby-on-mac-os-x-with-rvm/